# Python list append

Tags: python, list, append

I want to store the intermediate values of a variable in Python. This variable is updated in a loop. When I try to do this with a `list.append` command, it updates every value in the list with the new value of the variable. How should I do it?

```
while (step < maxstep):
    for i in range(100):
        x = a*b*c
        f1 += x
    f2.append(f1)
    print f2
    raw_input('<<')
    step += 1
```

Expected output

```
[array([-2.03,-4.13])]
<<
[array([-2.03,-4.13]),array([-3.14,-5.34])]
```

Printed output

```
[array([-2.03,-4.13])]
<<
[array([-3.14,-5.34]),array([-3.14,-5.34])]
```

Is there a different way of getting what I want in Python?

Comment: What is the meaning of `condition` and `m`? What is `fi`? What is `f()`?

Comment: X is updated based on a function ,
m is the range of the for loop,
the while loop runs for an arbitrary number of steps

Comment: But now I'm confused, I see that you have `f1` and `fi` is that a typo in your code?

Comment: That is a typo :) thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the original had a typo and `f1` is actually `fi` (or vice versa):

`fi` is a pointer to an object, so you keep appending the same pointer. When you use `fi += x`, you are actually changing the value of the object to which `fi` points.

To solve the issue you can use `fi = fi + x` instead.

Comment: Ah!, I did not realize that there was such a difference between
f1 += x and f1=f1+x
It solved the issue :)

Comment: Added your solution for the next generations

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you meant something like this:

```
   f2 = []
   f1 = 0
   for i in range(100):    
       x = f()
       f1 += x
   f2.append(f1)
   print f2
```

Note that if `f1` is a mutable object, the line `f1 += x` doesn't create new object, but only changes value of `f1`, so all its occurrences in `f2` array are updated.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are appending the same array to the list, and then changing the content of the array.

You need to create a new array object each time you append it to `f2`.

Answer (score 1):

The object you are appending (fi) is mutable ([see Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)), meaning, in essence, that you are appending a reference to the object, not the object value. Therefore, both list index 0 and 1 are actually the same object.

You need to either create a new object (`fi = array()`) on every loop iteration or use the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another related question is "[How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)".

[Daren Thomas used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference/986339#986339) assignment to explain how variable passing works in Python. For the append method, we could think in a similar way. Say you're appending a list "list_of_values" to a list "list_of_variables",

```
list_of_variables = []
list_of_values = [1, 2, 3]
list_of_variables.append(list_of_values)
print "List of variables after 1st append: ", list_of_variables

list_of_values.append(10)
list_of_variables.append(list_of_values)
print "List of variables after 2nd append: ", list_of_variables
```

The appending operation can be thought as:

```
list_of_variables[0] = list_of_values --> [1, 2, 3]
list_of_values --> [1, 2, 3, 10]
list_of_variables[1] = list_of_values --> [1, 2, 3, 10]
```

Because the first and second item in "list_of_variables" are pointing to the same object in memory, the output from above is:

```
List of variables after 1st append:  [[1, 2, 3]]
List of variables after 2nd append:  [[1, 2, 3, 10], [1, 2, 3, 10]]
```

---

On the other hand, if "list_of_values" is a variable, the behavior will be different.

```
list_of_variables = []
variable = 3
list_of_variables.append(variable)
print "List of variables after 1st append: ", list_of_variables

variable = 10
list_of_variables.append(variable)
print "List of variables after 2nd append: ", list_of_variables
```

The appending operation now is equivalent to:

```
list_of_variables[0] = variable --> 3
variable --> 4
list_of_variables[1] = variable --> 4
```

And the output is:

```
List of variables after 1st append:  [3]
List of variables after 2nd append:  [3, 10]
```

The difference between variable and list_of_values is the latter one changes in-place.