# Python list unwantedly updating appended lists

Tags: python, stack

I need to use a stack to push and pop lists with 2 numbers in them, that serve as XY coordinates in a program I'm making. It seems simple enough, so I just do

```
stack = []
```

to make the list I'll use as a stack. Now i make the coordinate variable

```
coord = [0,0]
```

and push it to the stack.

```
stack.append(coord)
```

Now, the stack is equal to

```
[[0, 0]]
```

and that's perfect. Now let's say I move up one, so my coord variables Y value updates like

```
coord[1] += 1
```

and coord equals

```
[0,1]
```

which is good. But wait! Even though I did nothing to the stack list, it now reads

```
[[0,1]]
```

when I wanted it to retain it's old value that I sent to it.

```
[[0,0]]
```

Why does this happen, and what can I do to accomplish what I want?

Just in case it wasn't clear, I want the stack to behave like

```
>>> stack = []
>>> stack
[]

>>> coord = [0,0]
>>> stack.append(coord)
>>> stack
[[0, 0]]

>>> coord[1] += 1
>>> stack
[[0, 0]]

>>> stack.append(coord)
>>> stack
[[0, 0], [0, 1]]
```

but this is what it does.

```
>>> stack = []
>>> stack
[]

>>> coord = [0,0]
>>> stack.append(coord)
>>> stack
[[0, 0]]

>>> coord[1] += 1
>>> stack
[[0, 1]]

>>> stack.append(coord)
>>> stack
[[0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

Changing `coords[1] += 1` to `coords[1] = coords[1] + 1` does not fix the problem, like it did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279599/python-list-append).

Comment: Also see [Python list of lists, changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/4014959) and associated links. For further discussion see [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by SO stalwart Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 3):

You are repeatedly appending the same `coords` reference to `stack`. When you change `coords`, all elements of `stack` appear to change.

What you should do instead is append a *copy* of `coords`:

```
stack.append(coord[:])
```

The `[:]` makes a copy.